# Manually updating samsung home app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, updates, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy Y phone. I couldn't help notice that the Samsung Home app in my mobile phone misses a lot of features in comparison to that in more expensive models of Samsung phones.

I tried getting my hands on the .apk file of Samsung home, but apparently, it is not available in Google Play or any of the alternative markets that I know about.

My Question is, will the latest version of Samsung Home even work on my phone, if I am able to get it somehow? (From the /system/apps folder of some rooted Samsung Galaxy S mobile phone)

Answer (score 0):

Check the ADW launcher. An open desktop, lots of functionalities (does not replace the notification bar as it's an integral part of the system